# Javascript with jQuery mobile and phonegap not working as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova

I am developing an iphone app on phonegap and I am using jQuery mobile. I want to implement a simple functionality on a page like when press a button on my html page, check if I have internet connection. If I do, then proceed on the next page else, display the error page.

I include the libraries:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="lib/jquery.mobile-1.0b1.min.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jquery-1.6.1.js"></script>  
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="phonegap.0.9.5.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="functionality.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jquery.mobile-1.0b1.min.js"></script>
```

my html code of page1.html is:

```
<a href = "#map_page" id='map_button' data-role="button" onclick = "connection();">Go!</a>
```

Now the functionality.js file contains the connection() function which is written according to the phonegap's docs:

```
function connection(){
alert('checking...');
// check if there is internet connection
navigator.network.isReachable("google.com", isNetworkAvailable, {});
```

}

```
function isNetworkAvailable(status) {
     var networkState = status.code;
     alert('Connection Type ' + networkState + ' - ' + status.message); }
```

The problem is that I am never getting in the connection() function, not even when I use the following script in my html page:

> $('#map_button').click (function(event) {
>                                               checkConnection()});

I've been working on this piece of code for a few days without being able to make it work. I would really appreciate your help...

Comment: is `connection` defined in a closure or is it added to the global object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was also having trouble getting checking for a connection but found an alternative method of doing it using var networkState = navigator.network.connection.type; I've implemented it quite differently binding a switched function to all my links. As it maybe on interest in the deviceReady method I bind all links to call a function that will decide whether or that link needs connection checking or not. Skip to second function for connection stuff!

```
 function onDeviceReady()
{

    //Bind all links and intercept them before they go anywhere //I'm jquery dependant 
    $('a').bind('click', function(event) {
        switch($(this).attr('id'))//using the id value of the link we help us decide what kidn of action we are doing
        {
            case "data-loader-page":
                return event;
            break;

            case "load-version-data": //I'm about to pull JSON data from a server

                if(!checkConnection()){return false}; //check for connection and exit if it fails.

                doJSON(); //at this point we have a connection so go get remote data.
                return false;
            break;

            //for un-handled links we will assume that you just want to hash bang
            default: return event;
        }
    }); 
}
```

This function works just fine for me and you can call it inline on your onclick event if you want. It doesn't depend on jquery either.

```
function checkConnection() {
    var networkState = navigator.network.connection.type;

    var states = {};
    states[Connection.UNKNOWN]  = 'Unknown connection';
    states[Connection.ETHERNET] = 'Ethernet connection';
    states[Connection.WIFI]     = 'WiFi connection';
    states[Connection.CELL_2G]  = 'Cell 2G connection';
    states[Connection.CELL_3G]  = 'Cell 3G connection';
    states[Connection.CELL_4G]  = 'Cell 4G connection';
    states[Connection.NONE]     = 'No network connection';

    if(states[networkState]==states[Connection.NONE] || states[networkState]==states[Connection.UNKNOWN]){
        alert('A network connection is required to access this page.');
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;    
    }
}
```

I'm jquery / jquery mobile dependant

```
<div data-role="page" data-theme="b" id="sql-manager-page">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>SQL Manager</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
        <ul data-role="listview">
            <li><a href="#data-loader-page" id="data-loader-page">Data Loader</a></li>
                <li><a href="#load-version-data" id="load-version-data" rel="external">Load version data</a></li>
        </ul>


    </div>
    <div data-role="footer">
        <h4> <a href="#privacy-page">Privacy</a></h4>
    </div>
</div>
```

Not the most elegant example I know but I hope this helps;

Comment: I get navigator.network.isReachable() and navigator.network.connection resolving as undefined. is there something special you need to do to have access to those variables? i've got gps stuff working, so i have access to some of the phonegap api stuff.  any thoughts?

Comment: @Landon I don't recall having anything special setup for this. This was working fine for me in an xcode project setup with phoneGap and including the phoneGap 1.0.0 js. The only 'special' thing was to call this after the device/phonegap and all the garb was ready....         document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried changing your HTML to:

```
<a href="#map_page" id='map_button' data-role="button" onclick="connection">Go!</a>
```

Without the `()`? Usually if you add the `()` it will execute the function and replace it with the return value of that function. I'm not 100% positive that happens in the HTML onclick attribute though.  Worth a shot.

Your second try looks like the wrong function name, `checkConnection()` vs `connection()`

Comment: I assume you are referring to my first suggestion. I wasn't very confident that it would. The second should work though.

Comment: @Nathan Loyer: Your suggestion of removing the () is not working. Have you got any other suggestion? About the name of the function, in my code is correct as I have different names.